# Using SQLite, possible to populate a listview in a fragment activity based on the column value of the selected list item in the previous activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

This is a construction material list making application.

In the main activity a listview populates with names of all current construction projects.  Each project has a rowid in the projects table.

There is also a lists table.  Each list will belong to a project and there can be several lists for one project.  Each list (row) in the lists table will have a project rowid corresponding to the project it belongs to.

The goal is to be able to select a project from the main activity, start the fragment activity, and populate only the lists belonging to the project selected.  Is this possible?  How can this be done?  Someone please help me.

I am not showing code because I feel like it's pretty basic.  Was thinking I need to pass the project rowid into the fragment activity and create a fetch method with where clause to display only lists that contain matching project rowid.  Ideas?

Comment: i find answer in your question itself..anything specific you are looking for in the answer?

Comment: Having trouble creating fetch method inside fragment activity.  Try to use the same fetch method created in database adapter class, but when it comes to the table and the columns "cannot resolve symbol 'LISTS_TABLE'".  Same thing with the columns.  Also, I don't really know how to structure the query so that the cursor adapter uses the passed project rowid variable.

Comment: well in that case in you need to post your `databasehelper` class and `fragment activity` class code to help us get the clear picture..

Comment: This is the main activity https://github.com/JohnnyJacker/GoFor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gofor/gofor/MainActivity.java  This is the fragment activity  https://github.com/JohnnyJacker/GoFor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gofor/gofor/CurrentProjectDrafts.java  This is the Database adapter class  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259809/how-to-reuse-method-within-database-adapter-class-in-fragment-activity-to-popula

Comment: can you post Logcat of error you get inside `CurrentProjectDrafts.java` class?

Comment: The code you are looking at doesn't trigger any errors at this time.  As of right now it populates all lists regardless of what project is selected.

Comment: @JohhnyJacker i know where the issue lies in your code..I will do one thing i will pull the entire repo once i reach my development machine at home and get back to you..

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this, but I did get it working.  See below for a solution.

Comment: Yeah!!That's right..I was going to suggest you the same..cool! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main activity select your project.
get the ID (primary key) of your project
send the ID to fragment Activity as parameter.
then open new activity. 
in loading fragment activity, get the lists of the project ID you have

Comment: I can putExtra/getExtra on the project rowid from the main activity to the fragment.  How do I put together a query inside the fragment activity that uses the project rowid as search criteria?

Comment: Here is a link to the code if you care to take a looksie.  https://github.com/JohnnyJacker/GoFor

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me.

Gave the getCurrentLists method inside database adapter a parameter.  On fragment activity start it gets the project rowid variable from main activity list selection and passes it in as a parameter argument to the cursor for simple cursor adapter.

If I am not using the right terminology please correct me, so I can learn faster!  Thanks for the push!

Below is my **CurrentProjectDrafts.java**

```
public class CurrentProjectDrafts extends Fragment {


NewProjectDatabaseAdapter db;
String sqlNewListProjectRowid;






@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_project_drafts_tab, container, false);

    String project_rowid = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("project_rowid");
    sqlNewListProjectRowid = project_rowid;

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), project_rowid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    try{
        openDB();
        NewProjectDatabaseAdapter dbFetch = new NewProjectDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());



    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


//Testing fetching projects info from database to populate list
    Cursor cursor1 = null;
    try {
        cursor1 = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.getCurrentLists(project_rowid);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor1);


///setup mapping from cursor to view fields//////
    String[] fromDatabase = new String[]
            {NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.KEY_LIST_NAME};

    int[] toList = new int[]
            {R.id.project_name};

////create adapter to map columns of database to rows in listview
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter1 =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.main_activity_projects_list_item,
                    cursor1,
                    fromDatabase,
                    toList,
                    0
            );

    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.currentProjectDraftList);

    lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter1);

    return v;
}


//This method creates a new instance of open database method in NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.java
private void openDB() throws SQLException {
    db = new NewProjectDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
    NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.open();


}
}
```

This is the fetch method that was created in my **NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.java**

```
public static Cursor getCurrentLists(String project_rowid) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor bCursor = ourDatabase.query(LISTS_TABLE, null, "project_rowid=?", new String[]{project_rowid}, null, null, null);
    if (bCursor != null){
        bCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return bCursor;
}
```